# How to type German special characters in TeXstudio on Mac OS with US keyboard layout?

Tags: texstudio, mac

I want to type German special characters like ü/ä/ö using a US keyboard.

In all other programs I can just press the character 'u' wait for a second and then select the special character 'ü' on a popup. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in TeXstudio. I even selected the option "Disable work-around on accent typing (Mac only) in the preference of TeXstudio. But it still doesn't work. I assume it's a bug.

My workaround so far is to use "u for ü, but this messes up the spelling correction.

Does anybody know how to get the usual Apple keyboard popup?

Comment: Does `alt+u` and afterwards `u` work? see http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/misc/typingumlauts.html

Comment: It works thanks. But it's not ideal. Very easy to mess up the order while typing fast.

Comment: Personally I simply remapped the keys, for example for `ü` I type `alt+u` and so on.

Comment: you can try this: https://hci.rwth-aachen.de/USGermanKeyboard

Comment: Try this ÃŒ = ü, Ã€ = ä, Ã¶ = ö

Answer (score 3):

To type umlauts the following keyboard shortcut works: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and afterwards <kbd>u</kbd>,<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to get your desired umlaut.

Personally I find this inconvenient, so I remapped the umlauts to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> = ü etc.

Remapping can for example be done via https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl} 
\begin{document}
Umlaute: \"u \"a \"o \"A \"O \"U
\end{document}
```

leading to 
[image]

Comment: yes but this screws up the spelling checker.

Comment: Then I can't help you as I am not using Mac.